# Using a variable for scp -i does not work but passing the filename works

Tags: bash, jenkins

I am using SCP to do a file transfer, however, when I specify the key file using a variable name, I get the following error:

> Warning: Identity file RPD-API.pem  not accessible: No such file or
>   directory.

The command I use is:

```
scp -i $SSH_KEY_PATH -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $WORKSPACE/test.war root@$MQ_IP:/home/test/ROOT.war
```

I am new to bash, but I feel this is something simple and I just lack familiarity. When I hardcode the key file name, there is no issue. For example:

```
scp -i RPD-API.pem -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $WORKSPACE/test.war root@$MQ_IP:/home/test/ROOT.war
```

When I print the variable value, it looks correct:

```
$ echo $SSH_KEY_PATH
RPD-API.pem
```

Comment: What does `declare -p SSH_KEY_PATH` show? Any special characters hidden in there?

Comment: Ok, after I executed the command, it seems there is a space and new line in the variable. the following is the output: declare -x SSH_KEY_PATH="RPD-API.pem
"

Comment: @JohnKugelman thanks for the advice, I managed to fix it after removing the new line. I'll post the solution here.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to John Kugelman for the clue. The variable had a carriage return at the end of it. In order to fix the issue, I had to to remove it. I did it using the following method:

```
CLEANED_KEY=${SSH_KEY_PATH//[$'\t\r\n ']}
scp -i $CLEANED_KEY -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $WORKSPACE/target/razer-pay-backend-mq.war root@$MQ_IP:/home/jenkins/ROOT.war
```

The difference in output is as follows:

Before cleaning

```
declare -x SSH_KEY_PATH="RPD-API.pem
"
```

After cleaning

```
declare -- CLEANED_KEY="RPD-API.pem"
```